# MVC partial view with int model throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a partial view that allows an int to be updated using the jQuery spinner plugin. This is shown in a qtip tooltip.

```
@model int
    ...
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new { @class = "spinner" })
```

and the controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult TaskPriority(int id)
{
    var task = Task.Get(id);
    return PartialView("TaskPriority", task.Priority);
}
```

When I call the action from my page I get:

> Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: name

The exception is thrown on the TextBoxFor line.

So what am I doing wrong here and why is it wrong? Am I overcomplicating it?

Comment: your `textboxfor` should be like this `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, new { @class = "spinner" })`

Comment: @Jaimin There is no Id property.

Comment: see my example ans i just post.

Answer (score 3):

View engine tries to retrieve name for the text box. Generally it is constructed from the name of the property being used as a source for the text box. Note how first parameter of `TextBoxFor` described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703538%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

> expression
>
> An expression that identifies the object that contains the
>   properties to render.

In this case there is not property, and therefore there is nothing to get name from.

To resolve it you can use `Html.TextBox` and specify name explicitly:

```
@Html.TextBox("priority", Model, new { @class = "spinner" })
```

Comment: Will it still be able to bind correctly with Textbox( instead of TextBoxFor(. Sorry I'm still a bit of an MVC noob.

Comment: @BlackKnight, well, it will insert necessary value into the text box, and on form post it will send parameter with name you have provided (`priority` in the answer) to the server. Does it suit your definition of `bind correctly`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would really suspect some problem using a primitive type as model.

You could do

```
@model Task

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Priority, new{@class="spinner"})
```

and in your controller

```
return PartialView("TaskPriority", task);
```

Solution2 :
use a `ViewModel`, with only one integer property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Model**

```
  public class RegisterModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model RegisterModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ID, new { @class = "spinner" })


or
@Html.TextBox("ID",null, new { @class = "spinner" })
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult TaskPriority(int ID)
{
    var task = Task.Get(ID);
    return PartialView("TaskPriority", task );
}
```

Comment: task.Priority is not a RegisterModel. You're missing some mapping in controller.

Comment: still wrong. You need (after `Task.Get(ID)`) `var model = new RegisterModel{ID = task.Priority}; return PartialView("TaskPriority", model);`